# Clear modal form textbox from value on closing event

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have a "Subscribe" modal form that opens when the users clicks on "Inscription"
and I wish that the data typed in it by the user disappears or the modal 'resets' the value when it's closed.

I tried multiple options but nothing worked.

```
Here is a link to a fiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0tekp47g/3/

```
solution:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0tekp47g/29/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(".modal input").val("");
    $('.modal select').val("");
});
```

Try it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0tekp47g/21/).

Comment: doesn't seem to work, I select anything then click on "annuler" to close the modal, open it again but it's still on the selection, on refresh the select is on the empty value vut "professeur" or "eleve" (depending on what I choose before) is shown in the selector

Comment: No, the values are cleared when the modal closes. Have you tried testing it on the JSFiddle link I provided?

Comment: @VictorLernout, It's working as intentded in my browser. What browser are you using? Are you trying it on the link I've provided?

Comment: ok! yes it works! I just had to put the slectino script in the code you gave me! thank you!

Comment: Glad I could be of help.. Happy coding! :)

Comment: I found something intriguing... The script works on jsfiddle but not on local even if the code is exactly the same